# PHP Login Page is Not Redirecting When correct Info is entered,

Tags: php, html, forms

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="US-ASCII">
<title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="checklogin.php" name="login">
<table>
<tr>
    <td><label for="login">Login</label></td>
</tr><tr>
    <td>
      <label for="email">Email: </label>
              <input type="text" name="email">     
              <br><label for="password">Password: </label>
               <input type="password" name="password"><br></td>
</tr><tr>
    <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login"></td>
</tr>
</table></form></body>
</html>
```

Above is my login.php Page which then redirects to checklogin.php which contains this code:

```
<?php
require 'dbConn.php';
$tableName = "logins";
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = hash(sha512, $_POST['password'], false);
$db = pg_query($dbc, "SELECT * FROM $tableName WHERE email='$email' and pass='$password'");
$count = pg_num_rows($db);

if ($count == 1){
    $_SESSION['email']=("$email");
    $_SESSION['password']=($password);
    header("location:portal.php");
} else {
    echo "Wrong Email or password";
    header("location:index.php");
}

?>
```

When I run this using correct credentials the index.php just seems to refresh it doesnt even look like it redirects to checklogin.php at all. Just to be clear all the files are in the same directory so it shouldn't have to do with the file placement but if you cant find the issue just try to tell me something i can check that you think might make this code not work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a [session_start()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) anywhere?

Comment: Have you tried location with the first letter uppercase? Location

Comment: @MarkBaker that's true too

Comment: @Mark Baker I am new to PHP so would i stick that in the if($count == 1)?

Comment: How about you try debugging?? At a minimum just echo out $count rather than redirecting

Comment: @Goikiu I keep everything lowercase due to camo case/uppercase causing issues with databases

Comment: @KingStixs - no, you'd stick it at the top of the login.php script, and need it in your portal.php script as well

Comment: "he index.php just seems to refresh it doesnt even look like it redirects to checklogin.php at all"... that's because your else case redirects you back there. remove header location on the else case.

Comment: maybe your password encryption algorithm is different than inserted password. Try

Comment: @KingStixs ... and please tell me where a php command like header will be put into your database o_o

Comment: And the php documentation http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php want the Location with the first letter uppercase...

Comment: @Goikiu i was saying its just habbit to have all lower case..

Comment: @KingStixs try to put it uppercase (only the first letter), then do what the others had said. Like session_start as example.

Comment: Found the error it was in a separate file where i typed a variable wrong but thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script contains a lot of errors.

```
$password = hash(sha512, $_POST['password'], false);
```

I suppose you don't define this constant. So here should be

```
$password = hash("sha512", $_POST['password'], false);
```

---

```
$db = pg_query($dbc, "SELECT * FROM $tableName WHERE email='$email' and pass='$password'");
```

For the first, don't write SQL in this way. At least you have to use placeholders or quote value for SQL.

Also, you use postgresql, so sql case-sentence. It means that my@email.com doesn't equal My@email.com.

---

You use $_SESSION but I don't see session_start anywhere.

---

```
echo "Wrong Email or password";
header("location:index.php");
```

this is wrong. You must not output any data before commands which affect header, e.g: header, setcookie, session_start, etc...

---

close php tag isn't recommended in php files.

---

And finally, try to debug error. Set up xDebug/zend debug or just use echo "debug info"; and exit ...

Good luck..

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a `session_start()` at the beginning of every page that should use the `$_SESSION[]` variables. In your case `index.php` and `portal.php`.

Then, if your login fails, you got an `echo` before the `header()` command which will cause an error. `header()` call must be always placed before any output.

```
<?php
session_start();
require 'dbConn.php';
$tableName = "logins";
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = hash(sha512, $_POST['password'], false);
$db = pg_query($dbc, "SELECT * FROM $tableName WHERE email='$email' and pass='$password'");
$count = pg_num_rows($db);

if ($count == 1){
    $_SESSION['email']=("$email");
    $_SESSION['password']=($password);
    header("Location: portal.php");
} else {
    header("Location: index.php");
}

?>
```

And you should take a look at [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) with [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) to prevent SQL Injection, which is easy possible in your case, because you input the `$_POST['email']` without escaping in the query.

Answer (score 0):

Just a note/hint:

Do NOT directly include the email in your query string. This creates a SQL-Injection hole! [reference](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)
Example:
If I'd enter: ' OR 1 == 1 --
It would create the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM logins WHERE email='' OR 1=1 --' and pass='$password'
```

which would return TRUE.. (note: -- opens a comment)

Use the [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) function here:

```
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
```

And don't forget to check first if it's not empty...